# MySQL update table row where column equals php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I know that `mysql_*` is obsolete today, but I need to use it anyway at the moment.
Could you please tell me how can I update a table where column equals php variable?

```
$qid = $_POST['idc'];
mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`table` SET `status` = 'canceled' WHERE idc = $qid");
```

Thank you

Comment: what is this `$qid = ['idc'];`??

Comment: just mistake, corrected

Comment: what is your table name?

Comment: So, MySQL is obsolete?

Comment: he mean,mysql_* functions :)

Comment: or use like `WHERE idc = {$qid}");`

Comment: Thank you, this is because of SQL injection?

Comment: Sorry but `idc = {$qid}` is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`table` SET `status` = 'canceled' WHERE `idc` = '$qid'");
```

Comment: If it helped you, please consider accepting the answer, tks!

Comment: Yeah, i can do it in five minutes and i will, tnx

Comment: Sounds great, I like it